# Specify parameters for menu functions

Tags: google-apps-script, menu

This is a snippet in the Google Apps Script for adding a menu in [Google Docs/Forms/Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus). As stated in the `Menu#addItem` method it calls the `menuItem2` function, but the snippet didn't include a sample on how to call the `addItem` when you want to add parameters in function call, or is this not possible?

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
    .addSeparator()
    .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Sub-menu')
      .addItem('Second item', 'menuItem2'))
    .addToUi();
}

function menuItem2() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
     .alert('You clicked the second menu item!');
}

function menuItem2(PARAMETER_HERE) {
  // codes    
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't add parameters to functions called by a menu.

A simple workaround is to store parameters elsewhere (in scriptProperties for example) and read these parameters if parameter is undefined.

```
function menuItem2(PARAMETER) {
  // if PARAMETER is undefined then read default parameter in scriptProperties
  // codes    
}
```

In this configuration you can call the menuItem2 function from elsewhere in the script using a "normal" parameter and it will be handled as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass static parameters.
Moreover, you can even create a dynamic menu.

```
class DynamicMenu {
  constructor() {      
  const mySimpleParams = [["one", "1"], ["two", {aa: "objectparam"}], ["three", [["arrayParam"]]]]

  this.createMenu = (ui) => {
    const menu = ui.createMenu('My menu')
      mySimpleParams.forEach(param=>{
          //beware to name without strange characters
          const functionName = `function${param[0]}`
          const entryName =  `option-${param[0]}`
          menu.addItem(entryName, `menuActions.${functionName}`)
      })
     menu.addToUi();
  }
  
  this.createActions = () => {
      const menuActions = {}
      mySimpleParams.forEach(param=>{
          const functionName = `function${param[0]}`
          menuActions[functionName] = function() {mayParametrizedFunction(param[1])}
      })
      return menuActions;
  }

  function mayParametrizedFunction(param) {
         SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
               .alert(`Got you folk!: ${param}`);
  }
 }
}

const menu = new DynamicMenu();
const menuActions = menu.createActions()

function onOpen() {
  menu.createMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi())
}
```