# Script function not found: entries

Tags: google-apps-script, menu

Based on [Adding arguments to a function in the onOpen entries object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514412/adding-arguments-to-a-function-in-the-onopen-entries-object/17527883#17527883) , I'm trying to add entries to the menu of a google sheet.

I'm getting The error in the title:

> Script function not found: entries For more information, see `https://developers.google.com/apps-script/refere`

What am I doing wrong in my code below?

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Summary",
    functionName : "copyRowsByColumnPattern",
  },
  {
    name : "Summary2",
    functionName : "copyRowsByColumnPattern",
  }];

  ui.createMenu('Push to Sheet').addItem('Select Sheet', 'entries').addToUi();
}
```

Comment: What error are you speaking of?

Comment: `addItem('Select sheet', 'entries')` looks through your script for the function defined by `function entries() { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a menu, as indicated by the Apps Script [Menus guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), there are two routes:

1. [`Ui`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) class (for Docs, Forms, and new-version Sheets
2. [`Spreadsheet#addMenu()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addMenu(String,Object)) (for old-version Sheets).

Given a set of parameterless functions to run:

```
const entries = [
  {name: "function1", functionName: "foo"},
  {name: "function2", functionName: "bar"},
  {name: "function3", functionName: "baz"},
];
```

With the `Ui` route, you can only add items one-by-one:

```
const menu = _____.getUi()
//   .createMenu("menu title");
// OR
//   .createAddonMenu(); 
entries.forEach(function (menuItem) {
  menu.addItem(menuItem.name, menuItem.functionName);
});
menu.addToUi();
```

This approach allows defining separators and sub-menus as well, hence the one-by-one nature.

The [`Spreadsheet#addMenu`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addMenu(String,Object)) syntax allows direct initialization:

```
const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
wb.addMenu("menu title", entries);
```

Both routes require your Script Project to have defined `foo()`, `bar()`, and `baz()` prior to the [`Menu`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu) creation.

Note also that the Apps Script server is not persistent - if you define those functions programmatically in `onOpen`, they cease to be defined once the script has finished running, and would need to be redefined every time before they could be accessed.

Comment: Thank you, thats a great answer. What I'm trying to get at though is how to pass parameters to the SAME function through the ui service. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824783/how-to-pass-parameters-with-menu-items-in-apps-script . Can you comment on how to approach this?

Comment: Did you ignore the answer you received there? And for other questions like yours, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758181/google-app-script-how-to-add-parameter-in-additem-function-call ?

Comment: I saw that answer but don't completely understand what he meant. I asked for a code example.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to create a menu is as follows:

```
function onOpen() {
  // Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp, or FormApp.
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
    .addItem('Second item', 'menuItem2')
    .addItem('Third item', 'menuItem3')
    .addToUi();
}
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

Comment: But I want to pass parameters , please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824783/how-to-pass-parameters-with-menu-items-in-apps-script

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `.addItem('Select Sheet', 'entries').addToUi();`, you're passing the string **entries** as the second argument instead of the object `entries`.

Just change that to

```
.addItem('Select Sheet', entries).addToUi();
```

and it should work.

Actually, if you want to add multiple items at once, you need to use `addMenu`

So, it should be: `addMenu('Select Sheet', entries)`

Comment: Thank you. I made the switch but am now getting :Script function not found: [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: You're mixing your syntax - `addItem` takes two string arguments

Comment: @tehhowch Yes, you're right, I was thinking about `addMenu`.